# PHP - check if cell is empty

Tags: php, database-design

I'm writing a simple PHP page that is pulling information through into cards.
At the moment my script is hard coding the amount of "linktitle_1, linktitle_2, linktitle_3" etc that are able to be pulled through, at the moment it is 3, and if any of the 3 cells are empty they are still echoed out as empty, and with a comma afterwards.
What I want to do is to be able to print out any from 0-7 items of information. (The appropriate columns are present in the database)
Psuedo code would be something like this:

```
if (linktitle_1 = empty, linktitle_1_url = empty) {
echo '<p>linktitle_1</p>'}
else {
do nothing
};
```

I'm looking to do this with both the related links, and the link title sections. So I guess what I need to know is:

1. How do I escape the echo that these statements are to be inside of?
2. How do I use an if statement to check if something is empty/null?
3. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Code =

```
<?php
// DB details
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM relevant_topics";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Removing special characters from rows.
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $title_clean = $row["title"];
    $title_clean = strtolower($title_clean);
    $title_clean = preg_replace('/\s*/ ', '', $title_clean);   

    $class_clean = $row["class"];
    $class_clean = strtolower($class_clean);
    $class_clean = preg_replace('/\s*/ ', '', $class_clean);   

    $related_clean_1 = $row["related1"] ;
    $related_clean_1 = strtolower($related_clean_1);
    $related_clean_1 = preg_replace('/[.,]\s*/ ', '', $related_clean_1); 

    $related_clean_2 = $row["related2"] ;
    $related_clean_2 = strtolower($related_clean_2);
    $related_clean_2 = preg_replace('/[.,]\s*/ ', '', $related_clean_2); 

    $related_clean_3 = $row["related3"] ;
    $related_clean_3 = strtolower($related_clean_3);
    $related_clean_3 = preg_replace('/[.,]\s*/ ', '', $related_clean_3); 

    $related_clean_4 = $row["related4"] ;
    $related_clean_4 = strtolower($related_clean_4);
    $related_clean_4 = preg_replace('/[.,]\s*/ ', '', $related_clean_4); 

    echo'
         <div class="mix item '.$class_clean.'">
         <h3>'.$row["title"].'</h3>
         <p>'.$row["description"].'</p>
         </br>
         <p>Related Items:</p>
         <p>
         <a href="#myModal'.$related_clean_1.'" role="button" data-toggle="modal">'.$row["related1"].'</a>
         <a href="#myModal'.$related_clean_2.'" role="button" data-toggle="modal">'.$row["related2"].'</a>
         <a href="#myModal'.$related_clean_3.'" role="button" data-toggle="modal">'.$row["related3"].'</a>
         <a href="#myModal'.$related_clean_4.'" role="button" data-toggle="modal">'.$row["related4"].'</a>
         <a href="'.$row["related1_link"].'">'.$row["related1"].',</a> &nbsp;
         <a href="'.$row["related2_link"].'">'.$row["related2"].',</a> &nbsp;
         <a href="'.$row["related3_link"].'">'.$row["related3"].',</a> </p>
         </br>
         <div class="item-bottom '.$row["class"].'_counter">
         <a href="#myModal'.$title_clean.'" role="button" data-toggle="modal">See more</a>
         </div>
     </div>

    <div id="myModal'.$title_clean.'" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title modal-top-health">'.$row["title"].'</h3>
            <br>
            <p>'.$row["details"].'</p>
            <br>
            <a href="'.$row["linktitle_1_url"].'">'.$row["linktitle_1"].', </a>
            <p>'.$row["linktitle_1_desc"].'</p>     
            <a href="'.$row["linktitle_2_url"].'">'.$row["linktitle_2"].', </a>
            <p>'.$row["linktitle_2_desc"].'</p> 
            <a href="'.$row["linktitle_3_url"].'">'.$row["linktitle_3"].', </a>
            <p>'.$row["linktitle_3_desc"].'</p>    
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 ';


}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimize with a loop, store the output in a variable:

```
// build list of titles
$titles = '';
for($i=1; $i<=7; ++$i) {

   // check for data
   if($row['linktitle_'.$i.'_url'] != null && $row['linktitle_'.$i] != null) {

      // add to output
      $titles .= '
            <a href="'.$row['linktitle_'.$i.'_url'].'">'.$row['linktitle_'.$i].', </a>
            <p>'.$row['linktitle_'.$i.'_desc'].'</p>';
   }
}

echo '
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title modal-top-health">'.$row["title"].'</h3>
            <br>
            <p>'.$row["details"].'</p>
            <br>'.$titles.'
          </div>';
```

You can then change that `7` to any number.

You can use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape the values if they might break the HTML.

```
$titles .= '
      <a href="'.htmlspecialchars($row['linktitle_'.$i.'_url']).'">'.
      htmlspecialchars($row['linktitle_'.$i]).', </a>
      <p>'.htmlspecialchars($row['linktitle_'.$i.'_desc']).'</p>';
```

The same logic can be applied to the related links.

It could be optimized further at the database level by having a dedicated table for the titles:

> table: relevant_topics_titles
>   topic_id | title_id | name | url | desc

Where `topic_id` is a foreign key to join with your table `relevant_topics` while `title_id` is a number between `1` and `7` (or less or more).

You could then fetch all the titles associated with your topic id and loop through them to build the list of titles.